# What is the drop rate for the legendary weapon "Infinity"?

Tags: borderlands-2

The descriptions in game especially in the wiki are very confusing.  As follows,for the legendary weapon "Infinity":

> Infinity is obtained randomly from any suitable loot source but has an
>   increased chance to drop from Doc Mercy located in Three Horns -
>   Valley.

What is this "increased" chance to drop? 1%? 10%? And what's the base chance to start out?

Comment: Well, we know that the weighting of any given mob dropping a  Legendary is 0.00999999978 (relative to whites, which are weighted at 200), but it's hard to put that to a percent, nor do we know how much this is scaled for things that have a particular legendary they're predisposed to. "Abysmal" is a good TL,DR though. I'd just recommend cooking the thing up in Gibbed's editor.

Comment: Darn. I was really hoping to snag myself a Legendary Command Mod.  Been hoping to get one for some time, but it seems nobody actually has one of them.  Oh well.

Comment: Only drops from Vermivormous or chests/vending machines, so... good luck with that. (Again, just make it in Gibbed's editor.)

Comment: I feel bad, I really want to have a "legitimate" weapon. Guess'll have to turn to the dark side and do some editing.  Thanks for the tip. Also, just leave it as an answer.  I think it'll do (unless someone else has stats of some sort)

Comment: The most recent version is [here](http://blog.gib.me/2013/01/11/borderlands-2-save-editor-revision-146/). I'm loathe to provide that as an answer because it's so nebulous and doesn't answer the question at all, really. Using the [gearcalc](http://thegearcalculator.appspot.com/) can help with cooking up specific things.

Comment: I too must unfortunately recommend Gibbed's editor. After a very very extensive amount of play I've come to accept there's a fair amount of guns I'm unlikely to ever see without excessive farming or cheating. Also, with a Fire/Corrosion Siren and Shock Mechro, getting the wrong element is very annoying...but easily corrected with Gibbed's editor

Comment: @BenBrocka Are there tutorials online? I'm having a bit of trouble applying prefixes and titles to guns (they won't show up)

Comment: @Retrosaur prefixes are determined by parts and stats, I'm not sure you can ever manually populate that box. If a prefix/title applies the box should auto-fill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low. Really really really low. Legendary weapons drop with single digit percent chances at best, and that's from the proper boss (though some bosses seem to usually drop a legendary the first time when fought only).

There's no single percentage though, different items have different methods of obtaining:

> [Every time a Burner-type enemy drops a sniper rifle, the sniper rifle dropped has a .88% chance to be the Cobra.](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Cobra_(Borderlands_2))
>
> [Though the Infinity has a higher chance to drop from Doc Mercy, the chance of an actual drop is still staggeringly low, making far rarer to come by then its other Legendary brethren.](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Infinity)

Lots of people seem convinced the Infinity has a lower drop rate but I haven't found anywhere that lists drop chances formally (either from the game's code or crowdsourced experiments), and the Cobra's drop rate and method was released publicly by a gearbox employee (because no one had found it...)

There's a rumor going around that the [legendary drop rate from a boss is 1/20](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/638784-borderlands-2/answers?qid=334194) but from my own observations this seems optimistically high. Certain high-drop rate bosses like the Warrior seem to drop one about this often, but at best they'll drop *one* of their legendaries at this rate rather than having a 1/20 chance for each. Which means you'll probably have to fight Warrior >100 times to get one of each legendary he has, if you're lucky.

Answer (score 4):

There was a crowdsourcing attempt done by the borderlands subbreddit a while back. It only looked at a few guns, but the infinity is listed and dropped at absurdly low rates: 7/1248 or about 0.5%

src: http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/110c39/crowd_sourcing_project_v3/

Answer (score 3):

The wiki article recently had the following text:

> Though the Infinity has a higher chance to drop from Doc Mercy, the chance of an actual drop is still 0.07%(which is 1428 kills), making it extremely rare even compared to other legendaries.

Which was removed with no explanation.

Regarding a Legendary Soldier Mod, though... I've been [farming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdqGfiIChII) Leviathan's Treasure Room, and after some 10 runs I'm up one Legendary Siren and one Legendary Berserker! I may be insanely lucky, but the probability may just be better than Vermivorous.