# What is the drop chance of the Hornet from Knuckle Dragger?

Tags: borderlands-2

I need to get the drop chance for the Hornet from Knuckle Dragger. Can you provide the drop rates for the normal, true vault hunter and ultimate vault hunter modes?

Comment: Adding a little bit more information to your questions would be *extremely* helpful.

Comment: What would knowing the drop rate do exactly?  If its 1% then its 1% per kill.  You could do it a thousand times and it still might not drop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the drop rate for the legendary weapon "Infinity"?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104031/what-is-the-drop-rate-for-the-legendary-weapon-infinity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any drop rates on the internet anywhere, so I killed knuckledragger 100 times and got the hornet 4 times. 4% may not be accurate, but that's what I got through trial and it will be the same drop rate on Normal, TVHM, and UVHM.

Comment: Most dedicated legendary drops are around 1:30 from what I could gather.

Answer (score 3):

After spending one hour searching fo answers i found out that the drop rate is 9.333% and after knowing this i've been getting it loads lol

Comment: Give us some source, otherwise it's just a random number.

Comment: Confirmed by Jacob Vautier with 19 drops for 200 kills

Comment: @Timelord64 still a random number.